# Firebase - How to catch Firebase undefined path errors

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a nodejs app that uses Firebase as a backend store. Unfortunately, whenever a user forgets to give a valid child name, or no child name, my nodejs app crashes with "Firebase: invalid path" error. "Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]""

Is there anyway to catch this kind of error? I was thinking of using try-catch, but that won't work for async calls deeper in the nested loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just validate the path before you call .child()? Simple check for empty string and those forbidden chars

Comment: @Andre - That would be the easiest way out..but that is also highly inefficient if i have to check every parameter that is sent before i call .child() on it. The "undefined" ones are not that often, but I need to catch those errors instead of letting the app crash.

Comment: Validation of user input is not a matter of efficiency. If you allow your users to enter part of the path, you should validate that value.

Comment: True. But, in my case, the way the app is designed, chances of erroneous input is slim. Hence, it does not make sense to check for every input. But, when the erroneous input does come, it crashes my app. Hence, the question about catching that particular "undefined" path error.

Answer (score 0):

Prevention is better than curing.

So i think you should just check if the path is valid (no undefined or forbidden chars) before calling Firebase. In my experience it's (almost) always an undefined variable so the next should do the trick:

```
if(var x != undefined)
    //Do something
```

It may not be optimal but it will prevent errors and maybe even more efficient then catching all errors because it will limit the calls you make to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that. But, is it possible to catch the kind of error I mentioned in Firebase?